# How to make smaller widgets in the sidebar in Shiny?

Tags: r, widget, shiny, sidebar

I'm trying to fit more widgets into my sidebar by making each widget smaller (or reducing the distance between widgets). I know in ShinyBS, there is a "size" parameter, like `bsButton("data","Load Data",size="small")`. However, I mostly use `uiOutput` and then determine the type of widget in `server.R`. Anyone know of anything similar or otherwise easy way to make widgets smaller?

Comment: You'd need to just add some simple CSS yourself (this is assuming you're familiar with basic css)

Comment: I am a bit, but not as much when it's integrated with R. Any advice on how to do it?

Comment: It's completely independent from R. Just look at the HTML of the shiny app in the browser, preferably using Chrome's Developer Toolbar (or Firefox, it has a similar toolbar), look at the CSS of the element you want to change, and play around with it. Maybe look at a short tutorial of how to use the developer toolbar to change css if you don't know what I'm talking about.

Comment: Got it! Looks like I can just add it right into the UI page, like `uiOutput("layout", style="color:#808080"),`. Any idea which CSS option can be used to make the entire widget smaller?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to make "the entire widget smaller". You would need to make the padding narrower, the margins smaller, the text size smaller, the ling-height smaller, etc. There are tons of properties that act together, just have to experiment

Comment: Actually, [according to bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-sizes) you can add a `btn-sm` class to a bootstrap button to make it smaller. You can try that perhaps. But other than that it is mostly experimenting by yourself

Comment: There's also the bootstrap class `input-sm` for input elements. But you have to set it with jQuery. Example: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1860